# Comparing bool with 1 in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Is it correct to compare bool to 1?

In a legacy code I find often:

```
if (xyz.isCounterActive() == 1)
```

where sCounterActive() returns bool.

Obviously, `if ( xyz.isCounterActive() )` is sufficient, but If I change this, I don't know which side-effects it may cause. Software is big, buggy but the customer insists, that it is working.

Compiler is VS2008

Comment: It's correct, but not nice.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Yes thank you! I have not seen it first because of redundant casts.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz No problem, cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case result of `xyz.isCounterActive()` will be implicitly converted to `int`. There're many rules of implicit conversion, which can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast), for example.

Probably signature of `isCounterActive` changed since it was introduced, and the one, who changed it, forgot to modify all `isCounterActive` calls.

Comment: The first part is misleading, as the answer in fact seems quite simple (see the link I've posted under the question). 

As for the second part, integers were once commonly used in place of booleans, so it's more probable it is the original signature and usage of this function. Such "idioms" are very common in legacy code.

Comment: I don't see any significant difference between the integral promotion described in your linked answer and the implicit conversion mentioned above. Integral promotion is more specific, but this hardly seems misleading.

Comment: @Useless It's misleading in the sense that it suggests that you need to decipher these complex rules to get the answer, whereas the linked answer gives it *directly* in plain text as a quotation from the standard.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Yes, in that sense it would be clearer to focus on integral promotion rather than lumping it in with all possible implicit conversions.

Comment: Yes! I think this is the case. The original programmer was a C programmer and has not realized, there is bool in C++. One can clearly see his evolution of learning C++ during the 5 years :-)